# ActivatedRoute is declared but its never is read

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

como va? esta es mi primera pregunta en stack, soy bastante nuevo en esto,
estoy haciendo un curso de Udemy de angular6 y  tengo el siguiente problema al importar 
el ActiveRoute

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

me dice lo siguiente a modo de advertencia:

"ActivatedRoute is declared but its never is read"

[image: TS6133]

Y no me deja utilizarla en una variable, porque
al querer usar la propiedad "params"  me indica que no existe.

[image: params]

Como puedo solucionarlo? no he encontrado mucho al respecto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: el código va como texto y no como imagen, te pudieran votar negativo por esa razón; por favor edita esto y corrige lo mencionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás utilizando correctamente la inyección de dependencia. En el constructor, debes inyectar ActivatedRoute de la siguiente forma:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

En lugar de:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute = ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Como puedes ver, solo debes indicar el tipo. En cambio tú estás inicializando una variable con el typeof ActivatedRoute, y es por eso que lo que recibes no contiene la propiedad Params, como es lógico.

Comment: Gracias Gabriel, como dije soy muy nuevo en esto y errores tontos como este se me pasan por alto,ya lo cambié y está solucionado, saludos!

Comment: Si, no pasa nada Pablo. Me alegro haber sido de ayuda! :)